# HttpsUrlConnection: Response different from Postman API

Tags: https, inputstream, postman, httpsurlconnection

I am posting an https request to client's API ,testing from Postman API , I am getting proper response, response is in xml structure , however using the conventional way of httpsurlconnection api in java , I am getting response which is trimmed .

Response in Postman :

```
<data>
<status>02231013757|1518968|Failed</status>
<status>041580082657|1518969|Failed</status>
</data>
```

Response header in Java :

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=68735C46DABA9D068FE1DB1D0FE83454; Path=/awp; Secure Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 14 Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 13:25:26 GMT Content-Type: text/html X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
```

Response fetched as String : `<data></data>`

As you can find the content-length is 14 in  response header, so this issue is at client's service end or am I missing something ?

below snippet I am using to read the content :

```
  read = new InputStreamReader(rc.getInputStream() );  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
        int ch = read.read();  
        while( ch != -1 )
        {  
          sb.append((char)ch);  
          ch = read.read();  
        }
        resp = sb.toString();
```

Comment: solved, client is accepting the request to be in same session , hence session-id to be passed  along with request.